# Image file to vector of pixels with CImg?

Tags: python, c++, image, image-processing, numpy

I have this in python:

```
import Image
import numpy as np
import random

img = Image.open('img.jpg')

#turn img to list of rgb tuples and scramble 
pixels = list(img.getdata())
pixels.reverse()
random.shuffle(pixels)

#make new image using scrambled pixels
img2 = Image.new(img.mode, img.size)
img2.putdata(pixels)

img2.save('newimg.png')
```

I figured I should be working in c++ to keep stuff I learned last semester fresh in my head and to prepare for the class I have next semester which also revolves around c++. So, I found CImg and got a bit overwhelmed by the documentation. So, what would be CImg's equivalent of line 8?

My end goal is to be able to scramble an image using a known pattern, then use that pattern to unscramble later. I don't know if this is possible though. To me its a bit like asking the following:

given:

```
srand(x);
int rand_num = rand() % 10;
```

and 
    rand_num = 7

find x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as know `CImg` provides [iterators](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html) to loop through every pixel. As such and provided that your compiler support C++11, you could use [std::shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/) to shuffle the pixels of your image (see example below).

```
CImg<float> img("lena.jpg"); // Load image from file.
unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::shuffle(img.begin(), img.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
```

Comment: Cool. I thought I would have to convert the image to raw data and this is much better. Now, do you think undoing the shuffle is possible given a known seed?

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57 I'm not sure, but I don't think that this is possible dude.